# Как получить JSON файл с данными AppMetrica яндекса программно? Проблема в составлении GET запроса

Tags: java, android, любой-язык, yandex-metrika-api, okhttp

Взял [доки](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrica-mobile-sdk/doc/mobile-sdk-dg/logs/request-docpage/), там написано:

> Все параметры передаются в виде параметров GET-запроса в URL (кроме авторизационного токена).

Составил URL:

```
https://beta.api-appmetrika.yandex.ru/logs/v1/export/installations.json?application_id=MY_APP_ID_HERE&fields=install_timestamp&date_since=2016-07-01 00:00:00&date_until=2016-07-14 00:00:00&oauth_token=MY_TOKEN_HERE
```

При вбивании оного в браузер запускается скачивание JSON файла с данными. Но вот с помощью либы `OkHttp` либы не удаётся сделать тоже самое. Пробовал так:

```
public static void getAppInstals(String token, String appId) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("oauth_token", token)
            .add("application_id", appId)
            .add("fields", "install_timestamp")
            .add("date_since", "2016-07-01 00:00:00")
            .add("date_until", "2016-07-14 00:00:00")
            .build();
    String url = "https://beta.api-appmetrika.yandex.ru/logs/v1/export/installations.json";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .get()
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
            Log.d(TAG, "response.code(): " + response.code());
            String res = response.body().string();
            Log.d(TAG, "response.body().string(): " + res);
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Выводит:

```
D/OkHttp: Callback failure for call to https://beta.api-appmetrika.yandex.ru/...
D/OkHttp: java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=OK, url=https://beta.api-appmetrika.yandex.ru/logs/v1/export/installations.json}
 D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
 D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
D/OkHttp:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Если же убрать `.post(formBody)` и подставить URL, работающий в браузере, то никакие методы `Callback`-a не вызываются вообще.

**Засим вопрос:**

Что я делаю не так и как же надо сделать?

Comment: Токен надо либо в заголовок добавлять, либо как get параметр. То, что у вас в formBody это для получения токена, для api оно не нужно же.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, ничего не помогает( Либо ничего не происходит (судя по выводу в логи) либо такая же ошибка (пробовал и в хэдер добавить 0auth и в formBody и убрал остальные параметры в URL.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, чёрт... Во я лоханулся... У меня просто в фильтре для logCat был убран тэг, с коим выводилось сообщение. Простой запрос по URL выдал мне таки JSON( Всё виноват LG, коий по умолчанию спамит мне в логи с тэгом `Utils`)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была глупа - в logCat был фильтр, убирающий вывод ответа в логи. Нужный JSON возвращается по URL из вопроса. Вот этот код рабочий:

```
public static void getAppInstals(String appId, String token) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String url = "https://beta.api-appmetrika.yandex.ru/logs/v1/export/installations.json?application_id=" +
            appId +
            "&fields=install_timestamp&date_since=2016-07-01 00:00:00&date_until=2016-07-14 00:00:00&oauth_token=" + token;


    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .get()
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
            Log.d(TAG, "response.code(): " + response.code());
            String res = response.body().string();
            Log.d(TAG, "response.body().string(): " + res);
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```